# ES6 синтаксис. Как правильно записать?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

```js
const handleFiles = () => {
  return async handle => {
    let result;
    result = 'hello';
    return result;
  };
};
handleFiles().then(result => console.log(result)).catch(console.log(e));
```

Почему не срабатывает данный скрипт?

> Uncaught TypeError: handleFiles(...).then is not a function

Comment: Промисифицируйте функцию, если хотите использовать конструкцию then.catch

Comment: А разве она не работает с асинхом?

Comment: Это просимы все, async/await решает ту же задачу, но там нету then.catch

Comment: @uber42 не верю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `handleFiles` возвращает **функцию**, а не `Promise`, у которого есть метод `then`.

Для решению нужно либо вызвать возвращенную функцию, либо возвращать результат вызова:

```js
const handleFiles = () => {
  return async handle => {
    let result;
    result = 'hello';
    return result;
  };
};
handleFiles()().then(result => console.log(result)).catch(e => console.log(e));

const handleFiles2 = () => {
  return (async handle => {
    let result;
    result = 'hello';
    return result;
  })();
};
handleFiles2().then(result => console.log(result)).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let handleFiles = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let result;
    result = 'hello';
    resolve(result);
    if (false) {
      reject('error');
    }
});

handleFiles.then(result => console.log(result), error => console.log(eror));
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот как будет выглядеть ваша промисифицированная функция

```
const handleFiles = (str) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(str){
        let result = str;
        resolve(result);
    } else {
        reject('Укажите аргумент');
    }
  });
};
```

В resolve передаете аргумент для then, а в reject аргумент для catch

Реализация:

```
handleFiles('1').then(result => console.log(result)).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: async функции и так возвращают Promise, Нет нужды вызывать конструктор вручную